# Execute a task after the WebView is fully loaded

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-2

Is it possible to have a task automatically run after the `WebEngine` finishes loading? I know I can get a `Worker` from `WebEngine` to indicate loading progress, but it seems like repeatedly polling the `Worker` not an elegant solution (i.e. locking up program until page loads). I know I can do this with a `Task`, so can I get the `Task` for `WebEngine` somehow, and add an execute on complete command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sample based on the [WebView documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html):

```
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
  @Override
  public void changed(
    ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable,
    Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue ) {

    if( newValue != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED ) {
      return;
    }

    // Your logic here
  }
} );
```

---

As a lambda expression:

```
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  (ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable,
    Worker.State oldValue,
    Worker.State newValue) -> {
    if( newValue != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED ) {
      return;
    }

    // Your logic here
  } );
```

---

If you only want to listen to the next page load and not every subsequent page load, then stop listening after the page loaded.

To do that, then you can remove the listener (in the listener code) once it has started to execute:

```
webview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(
                ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable,
                Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
      switch (newValue) {
        case SUCCEEDED:
        case FAILED:
        case CANCELLED:
          webview
            .getEngine()
            .getLoadWorker()
            .stateProperty()
            .removeListener(this);
      }


      if (newValue != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        return;
      }

      // Your logic here
      System.out.println("page loaded");
    }
  } );
```

Comment: this is incomplete because the code will run every time the page finishes loading, either you have to remove the listener after the code is run or find another solution... method(); and then webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().removeListener(this);

Comment: @firephil I updated the answer to include the suggestion from your comment.

Comment: my saviour!! Thanks a lot jewelsea you saved my life entirely for this year!