# Determine when JavaFX WebView has finished rendering

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-2

I want to use the JFX snapshot functionality as soon as the `WebView` has finished rendering.  I can [determine when the `WebEngine` has finished loading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540461/3453226), but the worker will fire a `State.SUCCEEDED` before the `WebView` has finished rendering the page loaded by the worker.

I've tried `webView.setVisible(true)`, `webView.layout()`, `webView.requestLayout()`, `webView.autosize()`, etc.

How can I determine when the pixels are displayed within the `WebView`?  Alternatively, can I force the `WebView` to render and block until it is complete?

Answer (score 2):

The JavaFX WebEngine which WebView uses allows calls from javascript to Java, so you could put a call to Java in the onload attribute of the page body.  Check out the docs for WebEngine, especially the "Calling back to Java from JavaScript" section.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html